# Stop sound in AVAudioPlayer and shown AQDefaultDevice (173): skipping input stream Error Logs

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, dispatch-async

I have used AVAudioPlayer and set the numberofloop to -1 because I want to play the audio in an infinite loop. At first it works well, but in the middle of playing sound track, I got the following error log continuously and my sound track was stopped.

> 2017-02-22 10:08:28.863041 TestBridgingHeader[1092:30476] [aqme] 255: AQDefaultDevice (173): skipping input stream 0 0 0x0

I am using two media players to get fade in fade out sound. I played these two media players using blocks:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{});
```

Why does my sound track stop and why does it show AQDefaultDevice error logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in Xcode 8.

You can resolve it with these steps:

1. Select Product --> Scheme--> Edit Scheme.
2. Select Arguments.
3. Add OS_ACTIVITY_MODE setup "disable" to Environment Variables.

Comment: Beware: this will also suppress other system messages, like autolayout constraint conflicts!

Comment: isnt that just muting it but not actually solving it?